# get data from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$country_list =
array(
"AF" => "Afghanistan",
"AL" => "Albania",
"DZ" => "Algeria",
"AS" => "American Samoa",
"AD" => "Andorra",
"AO" => "Angola",
"AI" => "Anguilla",
"AQ" => "Antarctica",
"AG" => "Antigua and Barbuda",
    ..........
```

Now I have get the key from database but don't know how many like:

```
     $key='AL,AO,AG';
```

or

```
     $key='AG,AD,AS,AQ,AF';
```

I want add the key and value on array from first array to make new array be like the following:

```
$key =
array(
"AL" => "Albania",
"AO" => "Angola",
"AG" => "Antigua and Barbuda");
```

How can I do it?

Comment: A combination of array_flip(explode(',',$key)) and [array_intersect_key()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) should do the job.... but have you ever considered normalising your database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on Mark Baker's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318840/get-data-from-an-array/19318982#comment28614050_19318840):

```
$key='AL,AO,AG';
$mykeys = array_flip(explode(',',$key));
$result = array_intersect_key($country_list, $mykeys);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [AL] => Albania
    [AO] => Angola
    [AG] => Antigua and Barbuda
)
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/53960)

Comment: @Nader: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you explain?

Answer (score 1):

```
$country_list = array(
    "AF" => "Afghanistan",
    "AL" => "Albania",
    "DZ" => "Algeria",
    "AS" => "American Samoa",
    "AD" => "Andorra",
    "AO" => "Angola",
    "AI" => "Anguilla",
    "AQ" => "Antarctica",
    "AG" => "Antigua and Barbuda",
    ...
);

$key='AL,AO,AG';

$subList = array_intersect_key(
    $country_list,
    array_flip(explode(',',$key)) 
);
var_dump($subList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key='AL,AO,AG';
$key = explode(',',$key);
$key_array = array();
foreach($key as $k)
if (array_key_exists($k, $country_list))
    $key_array[$k] = $country_list[$k];
```

Answer (score 0):

can you save name and code in database
your table should look like this

```
--------------
|code | name |
--------------
|AL | albania |
--------------
|AO | Angola |
--------------
|AG | Antigiua and Barbuda |
```

then when you get codes like

```
$codes = 'AL,AO'
$codes2array = explode(',', $codes);
```

run this sql

```
SELECT code, name FROM tbl_name WHERE code IN ("'.implode('","', $codes2array).'");
```

then it's easy to select name without playing with arrays

hope you find my solution useful

enjoy :D